# What is the Devuan equivalent of the Debian debian-archive-keyring package?

Tags: apt, gpg, multistrap, devuan, debian-archive-keyring

Debian keeps the keys required for a successful multistrap installation  in a package called `debian-archive-keyring`.

(Multistrap is like debootstrap, but it can install packages from multiple repositories - e.g. the official repo plus your own organisation's repo.  https://wiki.debian.org/Multistrap.)

Devuan also has the package `debian-archive-keyring` - it contains the Debian keys and does not contain the Devuan keys.  In particular it doesn't contain the key `94532124541922FB`.

There is no `devuan-archive-keyring`.

An example `simple-config` on https://wiki.debian.org/Multistrap includes a configuration line:

```
keyring=debian-archive-keyring
```

The specified keyring package is installed in the filesystem being built.  Only packages from repositories signed with keys installed from `keyring` can be installed.

Which Devuan package contains the Devuan key `94532124541922FB`?

If none, how do I use multistrap on Devuan?

---

I notice that multistrap is invoking `apt-get` with the parameters:

```
Getting package lists: APT_CONFIG=/tmp/multistrap.tRoXhw apt-get  
  -o Apt::Architecture=armhf 
  -o Dir::Etc::TrustedParts=/multistrap-devuan-ascii/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d 
  -o Dir::Etc::Trusted=/multistrap-devuan-ascii/etc/apt/trusted.gpg 
  -o Apt::Get::Download-Only=true 
  -o Apt::Install-Recommends=false 
  -o Dir=/multistrap-devuan-ascii/ 
  -o Dir::Etc=/multistrap-devuan-ascii/etc/apt/ 
  -o Dir::Etc::Parts=/multistrap-devuan-ascii/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ 
  -o Dir::Etc::PreferencesParts=/multistrap-devuan-ascii/etc/apt/preferences.d/ 
  -o APT::Default-Release='*' 
  -o Dir::State=/multistrap-devuan-ascii/var/lib/apt/ 
  -o Dir::State::Status=/multistrap-devuan-ascii/var/lib/dpkg/status 
  -o Dir::Cache=/multistrap-devuan-ascii/var/cache/apt/ update
```

Is there a way of overriding these variables without hacking the multistrap code?

If I could set `Dir::Etc::TrustedParts` or `Dir::Etc::Trusted` I could fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is called `devuan-keyring` not `devuan-archive-keyring`.